# kafka consumer is not able to produce output

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have written kafka  consumer in scala. When I run consumer it is showing blank on console.
I have used below code:

```
  val topicProducer = "testOutput"

  val props = new Properties()
  props.put("bootstrap.servers","host:9092,host:9092")
  props.put("key.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
  props.put("value.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
  props.put("group.id", "test");

  val kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](props)
  val topic  = Array("test").toList
  kafkaConsumer.subscribe(topic)
  val results = kafkaConsumer.poll(2000)
  for ((record) <- results) {
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord(topicProducer,"key","Value="+record.key()+" Record Key="+record.value()+"append"))
  }
```

Comment: Consumer will never produce output or please edit question, from above code snippet, topicProducer = "testOutput" consumer should subscribe to same topic and not test topic. You can try step by step approach, 1. produce from command line tools 2. consume from command line tool, 3. If all configs are verified then you can jump to code.

Comment: I have written consumer as well as producer. This code snippet is from consumer function. I want to consume data from kafka,do some changes in the data , then write the data back to kafka in some different topic.
Data is already there in topic named "test". I want to push data in testOutput topic using kafka consumer -> processing -> Kafka producer.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to specify `auto.offset.reset` property so that your consumer is able to consume the messages from the beginning (equivalent to `--from-beginning` in the command-line )

```
props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
```

According to [Kafka docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#oldconsumerconfigs):

**auto.offset.reset**

> What to do when there is no initial offset in ZooKeeper or if an
>   offset is out of range:
>
> - smallest : automatically reset the offset to the smallest offset
> - largest : automatically reset the offset to the largest offset
> - anything else: throw exception to the consumer

**EDIT:**

Alternatively, if you are using the old consumer API then instead of `bootstrap-server host:9092` use the zookeeper parameter `--zookeeper host:2181` .

If this does not solve the issue then try to delete `/brokers` in zookeeper

```
bin/zookeeper-shell <zk-host>:2181
```

and restart the kafka nodes

```
rmr /brokers
```

Comment: Even after adding this property, I am not getting any data in "testOutput" topic. Fyi: I want to read from a topic (using consumer), make changesm save back to kafka(producer)

Comment: The issue you mentioned in your question had to do with the consumer side which is not able to read anything. Your consumer is reading from topic `test`. What is the content of this topic?

Comment: I have entered simple text using kafka-producer.sh script in test topic

Comment: What is the response you get from `kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server host:9092 --topic test --from-beginning` ?

Comment: kafka-console-consumer --zookeeper host:2181, --topic test --from-beginning
In console, I have to run this command to see data. So , Should I change property from bootsrap-servers to "zookeeper",hostname:2181 ?

Comment: @SachitMurarka Which kafka version are you using?

Comment: How to check kafka version?

Comment: What all changes are required in code? Could you please tell.

Comment: I found this jar. kafka-clients-0.11.0-kafka-3.0.0.jar
I think version is 0.11

Comment: ok. Have you tried the alternative options I've included in my edited post?

Comment: I didn't get what you said. I think I need to make some changes in the code. Right?

Comment: try to replace `props.put("bootstrap.servers","host:9092,host:9092")`
 with  `props.put("zookeeper","host:281")`

Comment: Tried that too, it is showing bootstrap.servers is missing . It is showing exception,

Comment: Ok, so ignore this. Now in your terminal try : `bin/zookeeper-shell host:2181` and then `rmr /brokers`

Comment: bin/zookeeper-shell host:2181 got executed but rmr /brokers is not found